# How to set an alert if something is not in an array once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hello I am trying to figure out how to set an alert("not a option") only once per onkeyup if the letter pressed is not in a a-z array.

When a correct onkeyup is pressed, then it runs through the array and removes it.
But I can't put it at the end of the function because it will pop up regardless...
And I can't put it in the loop because it will run multiple times.

```
//function that compares the letter inputted to the splitWord array
function checkLetter (letter) {
    //setting to false first to cover any input
    var letterGiven = false;
    //run a loop and compare the letter and splitword  
    for (i = 0; i < numberEmptySpaces; i++) {
        if (splitWord[i] === letter) {
            letterGiven = true;
            //if it is true then letter will equal emptydisplay and replace the "_"        
            emptyDisplay[i] = letter;
            //this updates the emptyDisplay with the letter that was given.      
            $('#randomId').html(emptyDisplay.join(" "));       
        }
    }  
    //if it is not true then you lose one live and the letter is unputted to userGuess array      
    if (!letterGiven) {
        livesRemaining--;
        userGuesses.push(letter);
        $('#wrongWordId').html("[ " + userGuesses.join(", ") + " ]");
        $('#livesId').html(livesRemaining);
    }
    console.log(userGuesses);
    console.log(livesRemaining);      
    //checking to see if the empty display is undated when onkeyup is actived
    console.log(emptyDisplay);      
}
```

(This is for a hangman game, it works, just trying to spice it up)

```
//function that will only allow a-z and space bar to be pressed
function availableLetters(letter) {
    var letterGiven = false;
    var alphabet = 'abc defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    //check to see if it splits when called, it does
    for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        if (alphabet[i] === letter) {
            letterGiven = true;
            //removes the current letter from the alphabet array      
            alphabet.splice(i, 1);
        }  
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

//starts the initial game
startUp();

//listens for an event, which is onkeyup
$(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
    //creates a variable and converts into a string
    //fromcharcode is a converts assigned number to a letter and event.which is the number
    //toLowerCase just lower cases any string inputed   
    var keyLetter = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    availableLetters(keyLetter);
    checkLetter(keyLetter);
    updateInfo();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Say I press `a`, you will validate it and remove it from alphabets. If i press `1`, you will give me `alert("not found")`. But if I press `a` twice what should happen?

Comment: You should better describe what you want to achieve. This isn't clear. Maybe you take the problem by the wrong side.

Comment: thats the main idea i want, as of now the alert would be a cover all and would display the not found, until i created separate arrays to push them in and alerts.

Comment: In a «hangman» game, I would record all key user has tried instead of removing them from an array.... And byt the way, counting attempts... ;)

Comment: oh yea sorry i already have them, i just didn't include a few functions to hopefully not confuse ppl, but it might have been the opposite. was just looking to see if someone knew an simple way to avoid the unintended alerts

Comment: If you record user's tries, instead of uselessly removing letters from an array, a newly try (letter not already in the tries array) would trigger an alert. If the try is not a letter (you can check this by checking keycodes), nothing happens, that's all.

Comment: I feel like I got your logic upside down and discouraged you. If you can create a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) with your whole code, I could check it with you. I feel like playing hangman. ;)

Comment: no no your fine, i didn't think of attacking  from that angle which makes more sense, thank you

Comment: Great! Just update this question if you get stucked on this new angle. I'll be notified. +1 for that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `indexOf` and according to that handle. And check the `userGuesses` array if don't want to show the alert again.

```
//function that compares the letter inputted to the splitWord array
function checkLetter (letter) {
    //setting to false first to cover any input
    var letterGiven = false;
    //run a loop and compare the letter and splitword 
    if(splitWord.indexOf(letter)>=0){ 

            letterGiven = true;
            //if it is true then letter will equal emptydisplay and replace the "_"        
            emptyDisplay[i] = letter;
            //this updates the emptyDisplay with the letter that was given.      
            $('#randomId').html(emptyDisplay.join(" "));       
        }

    //if it is not true then you lose one live and the letter is unputted to userGuess array      
    if (!letterGiven && userGuesses.indexOf(letter)<0) {
        livesRemaining--;
        userGuesses.push(letter);
        $('#wrongWordId').html("[ " + userGuesses.join(", ") + " ]");
        $('#livesId').html(livesRemaining);
    }
    console.log(userGuesses);
    console.log(livesRemaining);      
    //checking to see if the empty display is undated when onkeyup is actived
    console.log(emptyDisplay);      
}
```